# Calculating time differences for a column based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like this:

```
> df
                  time region place action
1  2019-01-14 16:00:08      A     G  START
2  2019-01-14 16:00:08      A     I   STOP
3  2019-01-14 16:00:16      A     H  START
4  2019-01-14 16:00:16      A     G   STOP
5  2019-01-14 16:01:40      A     H   STOP
6  2019-01-14 16:01:40      A     G  START
7  2019-01-14 16:01:54      A     G   STOP
8  2019-01-14 16:02:21      A     D  START
9  2019-01-14 16:02:31      A     C  START
10 2019-01-14 16:02:54      A     D   STOP
11 2019-01-14 16:03:12      A     C   STOP
12 2019-01-14 16:03:13      A     E  START
13 2019-01-14 16:03:34      A     E   STOP
14 2019-01-14 16:03:34      A     A  START
15 2019-01-14 16:04:12      A     A   STOP
16 2019-01-14 16:04:12      A     E  START
17 2019-01-14 16:04:17      A     E   STOP
18 2019-01-14 16:04:55      A     F  START
19 2019-01-14 16:05:08      A     B  START
20 2019-01-14 16:05:08      A     F   STOP
```

I want the difference between START and STOP between places in every region. (eg. difference between the time in line 1 and the time in line 4 because it is the closest STOP for this place). Here's what I've got so far: what i'm trying to do in the ifelse-construct is finding the next row with a STOP in the action-column.

```
df %>% group_by(region, place) %>%
  mutate(difference = ifelse(action == "STOP", NA, time[which(action == "STOP")[which.max(which(action == "STOP") > row_number())]] - time))

# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   region, place [9]
   time                region place action difference
   <dttm>              <fct>  <fct> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2019-01-14 16:00:08 A      g     START        8.52
 2 2019-01-14 16:00:08 A      i     STOP        NA   
 3 2019-01-14 16:00:16 A      h     START       84.2 
 4 2019-01-14 16:00:16 A      g     STOP        NA   
 5 2019-01-14 16:01:40 A      h     STOP        NA   
 6 2019-01-14 16:01:40 A      g     START      -84.2 
 7 2019-01-14 16:01:54 A      g     STOP        NA   
 8 2019-01-14 16:02:21 A      d     START       32.9 
 9 2019-01-14 16:02:31 A      c     START       40.8 
10 2019-01-14 16:02:54 A      d     STOP        NA   
11 2019-01-14 16:03:12 A      c     STOP        NA   
12 2019-01-14 16:03:13 A      e     START       21.3 
13 2019-01-14 16:03:34 A      e     STOP        NA   
14 2019-01-14 16:03:34 A      a     START       38.0 
15 2019-01-14 16:04:12 A      a     STOP        NA   
16 2019-01-14 16:04:12 A      e     START      -38.5 
17 2019-01-14 16:04:17 A      e     STOP        NA   
18 2019-01-14 16:04:55 A      f     START       13.4 
19 2019-01-14 16:05:08 A      b     START       NA   
20 2019-01-14 16:05:08 A      f     STOP        NA
```

The time-differences are correct except for the two negative ones (they should be ~14 and ~5). Does anybody have a idea why this is happening? Thanks!

The data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    time = structure(
      c(
        1547478008.024,
        1547478008.225,
        1547478016.168,
        1547478016.542,
        1547478100.374,
        1547478100.758,
        1547478114.589,
        1547478141.86,
        1547478151.972,
        1547478174.757,
        1547478192.723,
        1547478193.077,
        1547478214.37,
        1547478214.562,
        1547478252.523,
        1547478252.907,
        1547478257.458,
        1547478295.109,
        1547478308.358,
        1547478308.547
      ),
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
      tzone = ""
    ),
    region = structure(
      c(
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L
      ),
      .Label = "A",
      class = "factor"
    ),
    place = structure(
      c(
        7L,
        9L,
        8L,
        7L,
        8L,
        7L,
        7L,
        4L,
        3L,
        4L,
        3L,
        5L,
        5L,
        1L,
        1L,
        5L,
        5L,
        6L,
        2L,
        6L
      ),
      .Label = c("a",
                 "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    action = c(
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "STOP",
      "START",
      "START",
      "STOP"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 20L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: Will there always be no more that one stop after each start and before the next start in the same place? Because if the answer is yes, you can just arrange by time, region and place and use `lead()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is always exactly one STOP after each START and before the next START, this will work:

```
df %>% group_by(region, place) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(difference=ifelse(action=="STOP", NA, difftime(lead(time),time,units="secs")))

# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   region, place [9]
   time                region place action difference
   <dttm>              <fct>  <fct> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2019-01-14 10:00:08 A      g     START        8.52
 2 2019-01-14 10:00:08 A      i     STOP        NA   
 3 2019-01-14 10:00:16 A      h     START       84.2 
 4 2019-01-14 10:00:16 A      g     STOP        NA   
 5 2019-01-14 10:01:40 A      h     STOP        NA   
 6 2019-01-14 10:01:40 A      g     START       13.8 
 7 2019-01-14 10:01:54 A      g     STOP        NA   
 8 2019-01-14 10:02:21 A      d     START       32.9 
 9 2019-01-14 10:02:31 A      c     START       40.8 
10 2019-01-14 10:02:54 A      d     STOP        NA   
11 2019-01-14 10:03:12 A      c     STOP        NA   
12 2019-01-14 10:03:13 A      e     START       21.3 
13 2019-01-14 10:03:34 A      e     STOP        NA   
14 2019-01-14 10:03:34 A      a     START       38.0 
15 2019-01-14 10:04:12 A      a     STOP        NA   
16 2019-01-14 10:04:12 A      e     START        4.55
17 2019-01-14 10:04:17 A      e     STOP        NA   
18 2019-01-14 10:04:55 A      f     START       13.4 
19 2019-01-14 10:05:08 A      b     START       NA   
20 2019-01-14 10:05:08 A      f     STOP        NA
```

Note: If you're one 100% sure the assumption is accurate, you can use the following, which adds another `ifelse` to make sure the next row after a START is a STOP, otherwise giving an NA:

```
df %>% group_by(region, place) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(difference=ifelse(action=="STOP", NA,
    ifelse(lead(action)=="STOP",difftime(lead(time),time,units="secs"),NA)))
```

Comment: I'm 99% confident that it's always START-STOP-START-STOP-..., I'll check the real data. But look at the difference for h, it's changed from 84.2 to 1.4, so it was correct before and now it's wrong, that's strange, isn't it? But the rest is correct, that's a great start!

Comment: That's 1.4 minutes, the value is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Right, revised the code above so that it always gives the value in units of seconds. Now I'm curious why your code didn't have the same problem...

Comment: And now added a version that should work even if the assumption is not true.